# Manually update knockout observableArray

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I have an observable Array being populated by an AJAX call but it is not updating.

```
function ViewModel() {
    var self = this;
    self.FinanceTypes = ko.observableArray([]);
    self.Country = ko.observable('@Model.Country.CountryName');

    function FinanceTypeViewModel(data) {
        var self = this;
        self.Name = data.Name;
        self.Tax = data.TaxPercentage;
        //self.Accounts = data.AccountTypes;
    }

    self.getFinanceTypes = function() {
        var data = { country: ko.toJS(self.Country()) };

        $.getJSON("/Admin/GetFinanceTypes", data, function(result) {
            var mapped = ko.utils.arrayMap(result, function(item) {
                return new FinanceTypeViewModel(item);
            });
            ko.utils.arrayPushAll(self.FinanceTypes(), mapped);
            self.FinanceTypes.valueHasMutated();
        });
    }

    self.getFinanceTypes();
}
```

The problem line is

```
self.FinanceTypes.valueHasMutated();
```

everything else works. This gives an "Uncaught ReferenceError: Name is not defined"

If I change it to

```
self.FinanceTypes().valueHasMutated();
```

I get "Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function"

Thanks

Comment: Are you aware that ko.utils.arrayPushAll *appends* to the array instead of overwriting the current data? Is that what you want? You could instead write ´self.FinanceTypes(mapped)´ and Knockout will take care of calling valueWillMutate and valueHasMutated.

Comment: I thought that as well but no luck. I get the Name is not defined error

Comment: Have you considered that item might be undefined/null when calling FinanceTypeViewModel? Try logging item to the console and see what it looks like. The Knockout part is almost correct (you need valueWillMutate as well) but I recommend using the method I mentioned earlier as it does exactly the same (unless you actually want to append to the array)

Comment: Found the problem. The code above was actually fine, it was my binding - I was binding to Name instead of 'Name'. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

Calling `ko.utils.arrayPushAll(self.FinanceTypes(), mapped)` pushes all the items in `mapped` into the *unwrapped* `FinanceTypes`. Call it without unwrapping it and you won't have to call `valueHasMutated`: `ko.utils.arrayPushAll(self.FinanceTypes, mapped)`